# Can't uninstall tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I have some problem with uninstalling tensorflow-gpu, but i can't.
I've already uninstalled tensorflow, but it is still in my pc with the command import tensorflow [My error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSPCS.png)

Comment: Did you tried `conda remove --force tensorflow` . also you can manually remove it from the packages directory. The directory can be shown by using the following function `pip show tensorflow-gpu` for pip version. Best of luck

Comment: You are inside a virtual environment. Make sure that the os *sees* the correct `conda` command. Type `which conda` and it should say `.../base/bin/conda`. Then do the same with `python` to make sure you are running base's python instead the system's one. If they are correct make sure you don't have an alias that screws up either of those commands, type `unalias conda` and `unalias python` and do the same thing as before.

Comment: In the REPL, please type 'tensorflow.__path__' to see the package path and take appropriate action.